# What is the difference between Cartesian product and cross join?

Tags: sql-server

I am working on SQL Server 2008, and wanted to know about what is the differnce between Cartesian Product and Cross Join. Can somebody please help me to clear the concept?

Comment: You mean cartesian product? It is the same as cross join.

Comment: Have a look at the following article [SQL SERVER – Introduction to JOINs – Basic of JOINs](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/13/sql-server-introduction-to-joins-basic-of-joins/) Specifically at the section **CROSS JOIN**

Answer (score 41, accepted):

When you do Cross join you will get cartesian product. Each row in the first table is matched with every row in the second table

[image]

Comment: I got it, CROSS JOIN = Cartesian product.
Hope we achieve the same using, **select * from table1, table2;**

Answer (score 14):

### CROSS JOIN

> This join is a Cartesian join that does not necessitate any condition
>   to join. The resultset contains records that are multiplication of
>   record number from both the tables.

[image: cross join]

```
/* CROSS JOIN */
SELECT t1.*,t2.*
FROM Table1 t1
CROSS JOIN Table2 t2
```

**Sorce:** 
[APRIL 13, 2009 BY PINAL DAVE

SQL SERVER – Introduction to JOINs – Basic of JOINs](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/13/sql-server-introduction-to-joins-basic-of-joins/)

Answer (score 3):

Both the joins give same result. Cross-join is SQL 99 join and Cartesian product is Oracle Proprietary join.

A cross-join that does not have a 'where' clause gives the Cartesian product.
Cartesian product result-set contains the number of rows in the first table, multiplied by the number of rows in second table. (Resulting in a higher dimension in the resulting set).

Answer (score 0):

A cartesian join, also known as a cross join, is a type of join that produces the cartesian product of two relations. The cartesian product of two sets A and B is the set of all ordered pairs (a, b) where a belongs to A and b belongs to B.
In most cases, cartesian joins are not very useful because they produce a large number of rows that are not relevant to the query. However, they can be useful in some cases, such as when you need to generate a list of all possible combinations of two sets.

Answer (score 0):

*Cross JOIN*

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t1
CROSS JOIN Table2 t2
```

*Cartesian Prouct*

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t1, 
Table2 t2
```

They both have same result. i.e every row of table1 will be mapped with every row of table2
so total M*N number of rows will be there in final result

M=no. of rows in table 1

N=no. of rows in table 2

Answer (score -1):

Cartesian product does not have any condition and result set have total row as r=r1*r2 where r1 rows in first relation and r2 in second relation. joins satisfy specific conditions

Answer (score -1):

when we do a cartesian product of two tables we don't need to find any kinda matched column. But in Join one column must have to be matched from both tables.

Comment: What does this answer add to other answers already provided?