# How to join 2 tables without common column?

Tags: mysql, select, join

i have 2 tables

```
User Code         SubMenuID

usercol           menucol 
-----------       -------------
AB                Sub-01 
Alam              Sub-02 
CSRL
```

i want to show them like this

```
usercol           menucol
----------        ------------
AB                Sub-01 
AB                Sub-02 
Alam              Sub-01
Alam              Sub-02 
CSRL              Sub-01 
CSRL              Sub-02
```

How can i get this using sql query? It would be very helpful :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since the tables are not related by a foreign key relationship, you can not join them - what you want as a result, is the Cartesian product from the two tables. This is achieved by selecting from both tables without any additional join condition (this is also called a *cross join*):

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM userCode, SubMenuId;
```

This query combines all rows from the first table with all rows from the second table.

```
+---------+---------+
| usercol | menucol |
+---------+---------+
| AB      | Sub-01  |
| AB      | Sub-02  |
| Alam    | Sub-01  |
| Alam    | Sub-02  |
| CSRL    | Sub-01  |
| CSRL    | Sub-02  |
+---------+---------+
```

Comment: thnx for the clarification :)

Comment: what about cross join?

Comment: @DimaDz What I showed in the example **is** a cross join. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11861417/what-is-the-difference-between-cartesian-product-and-cross-join

Comment: sorry, my fault :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.usercol, b.menucol FROM UserCode a JOIN SubMenuID b
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from usercode,submenuid
order by usercol;
```