# Same results with cartesian product and JOIN

Tags: sql

What is the necessary condition to have the same result from a `JOIN` and a `Cartesian Product` ?

I don't think it is possible, if anyone can clear me will be great, thanks.I've searched but I couldn't an answer to my question.

Comment: also see FULL OUTER JOIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server, the `CROSS JOIN` join type can achieve the same thing as a cartesian product.  It matches every row from the left table to every row in the right. This is illustrated in the following SO question:

[What is the difference between Cartesian product and cross join?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11861417/what-is-the-difference-between-cartesian-product-and-cross-join)

And a little MS documentation also:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190690%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 1):

All three queries return the same result:

```
select *
from t1 cross join t2 

select *
from t1,t2 

select *
from t1 join t2 
on 1=1
```

Answer (score 0):

A cartesian product is equivalent to a join that always evaluates to true.
So

```
 Table1 join Table2 on 1=1
```

will give you a cartesian product.